# Последовательность операций в перегрузке операторов копии и присваивания

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте, пишу класс для работы со множествами. Использую перегрузку оператора присваивания и копии , а также перегрузку присваивания и копии с "переносом". Т.е всего 4 перегрузки. Я сделал трассировку программы, но так и не смог разобраться в какой момент происходит оператор копии или оператор копии с "переносом" (как программа решает что использовать) и тому подобное. Не всё так просто с этими перегрузками, надеюсь на подробный ответ.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Set {
    static int len; //Создание дополнительных множеств
    int n; //Мощность множества
    static bool mode; //0 обычный режим, 1 режим трассировки
    static int U; //Мощность универсума
    char litera; //Обозначение множества A,B,C,D...
    char* universe; //Указатель на множество
public:
    Set(char _litera);
    ~Set();
    Set();
    void print();
    int power() { return n; }
    //Операции над множествами
    Set operator & (const Set& B) const;
    Set operator ~ () const;
    //Перегрузка операторов копии и присваивания
    Set(const Set &);
    Set operator = (const Set&);
    //Перегрузка операторов копии и присваивания с переносом
    Set(Set &&);
    Set operator = (Set &&);
};


Set::Set() : litera('D' + (len++)), n(0), universe(new char[U + 1]) {
    if (mode) cout << "Создание множества " << litera << " = []\n";
    universe[0] = '\0';
};
Set ::~Set() {
    if(mode) cout << "Удаление множества " << litera << '\n';
    delete[] universe;
}
Set::Set(char _litera) : litera(_litera), n(0), universe(new char[U + 1]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < U; i++) {
        if (rand() % 2) {
            universe[n++] = '0' + i;
        }
    }
    universe[n] = '\0';
    cout << "Создание множества " << litera << " = [" << universe << "]\n";
}
void Set::print() {
    cout << litera << " = [" << universe << "]" << '\n';
}
//Операции над множествами
Set Set:: operator & (const Set& B) const {
    Set C;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.n; j++) {
            if (universe[i] == B.universe[j]) C.universe[C.n++] = universe[i];
        }
    }
    C.universe[C.n] = '\0';
    if(mode) cout << "Результат пересечения множества " << litera << " = [" << universe << "]" 
        << " со множеством " << B.litera << " = [" << B.universe << "]" << " => " << C.litera << " = [" << C.universe << "]\n";
    return C;
}
Set Set:: operator ~ () const {
    Set C;
    for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
        bool flag = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (ch == universe[j]) { flag = false; break; }
        }
        if (flag) C.universe[C.n++] = ch;
    }
    C.universe[C.n] = '\0';
    if(mode) cout << "Результат инверсии множества " << litera << " = [" << universe << "]" 
        << " => " << C.litera << " = [" << C.universe << "]\n";
    return C;
}
//Перегрузка оператов копии и присваивания
Set::Set(const Set & B) : n(B.n), litera(B.litera), universe(new char[U + 1]) {
    if (mode) cout << "Конструктор копирования множества " << B.litera << '\n';
    memcpy(universe, B.universe, U + 1);
}
Set Set :: operator = (const Set& B) {
    if(mode) cout << "Конструктор присваивания " << litera << " = " << B.litera << '\n';
    if (this != &B) {
        n = B.n;
        memcpy(universe, B.universe, U + 1);
        litera = 'R';
    }
    return *this;
}
//Перегрузка оператов копии и присваивания с переносом
Set::Set(Set && B) : litera('D'+(len++)),n(B.n), universe(B.universe){
    if (mode) cout << "Конструктор копирования множества " << litera << " из множества " << B.litera << " с переносом\n";
    B.universe = NULL;
}
Set Set:: operator = (Set&& B) {
    if(mode) cout << "Конструктор присваивания c переносом " << litera << " = " << B.litera << '\n';
    if (this != &B) {
        n = B.n;
        universe = B.universe;
        litera = 'R';
        B.universe = NULL;
    }
    return *this;
}

const unsigned int N = 1;

int Set::U = 10; //Мощность универсума для десятичных цифр
bool Set::mode = 1; //0 обычный режим, 1 режим трассировки
int Set::len = 1; //Создание дополнительных множеств;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));
    time_t start, stop;
    {
        Set A('A'), B('B'), C('C'), D('D'), E;
        system("pause");
        //Обработка множеств
        start = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            E = ((A & ~(B & C)) & ~D);
        }
        stop = clock();
        //Вывод всех множеств
        A.print();
        B.print();
        C.print();
        D.print();
        E.print();
        //Вывод средней мощности и времени
        cout << "Average power = " <<
            (A.power() + B.power() + C.power() + D.power() + E.power()) / 5 << '\n';
        cout << "Time = " << stop - start << '/' << N << '\n';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Трассировка программы]